# how to fix E2367 Can't inherit RTTI class from non-RTTI base 'exception'

Tags: boost, rtti, c++builder-2010

I am trying to use boost libraries to tokenize my string 'cause boost has powerfull string manipulation algorithms rather than STL but a little slower than but as I only need to tokenize a line at a time - it fits my need.

So, when add `#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>` inc file it gives several errors !

So how to fix error `E2367` (RTTI) ??? as Emb official site explains here `http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2366_Can't_inherit_non-RTTI_class_from_RTTI_base_OR_E2367_Can't_inherit_RTTI_class_from_non-RTTI_base_(C%2B%2B)` 
 it doesn't make sense to me!!

Please help!

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of the code you are using that produces the error.

Comment: What mekes you think that boost is slower than the STL?

Comment: Mark! I am using TIndy, devx, mydac components! Empty console project with `#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>` works well.

Comment: many people think boost has powerfull libs but not efficient in every case! They say that but I have a little experience in it. I wish it is powerfull of all!

Comment: Firstly I deleted all obj- compiled files but no success, then created empty project and added files, then i saw it's working !! I think it was because of different include files path addition!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that RTTI was turned off in the Project Options -> C++ Compiler -> C++ Compilation section. When the new project was created, RTTI could have been turned on by default.

See [this Embarcadero QualityCentral ticket](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=23557) for more details. Here are a couple of excerpts in case that gets zapped away to Embarcadero Neverland:

**Steps to Reproduce:**

```
bcc32 -c -RT- 238409.cpp

//exp : clean compile 
//res : 
Error E2367 D:\borland\dexter\Include\typeinfo.h 114: Can't inherit RTTI class from non-RTTI base 'exception'
Error E2367 D:\borland\dexter\Include\typeinfo.h 115: Can't inherit RTTI class from non-RTTI base 'exception'
Error E2238 D:\borland\dexter\Include\dinkumware\xlocale 649: Multiple declaration for 'codecvt<wchar_t,char,int>::in(int &,const char *,const char *,const char * &,wchar_t *,wchar_t *,wchar_t * &) const'
Error E2344 D:\borland\dexter\Include\dinkumware\xlocale 538: Earlier declaration of 'codecvt<wchar_t,char,int>::in(int&,const char *,const char *,const char * &,wchar_t *,wchar_t *,wchar_t * &) const'
Error E2238 D:\borland\dexter\Include\dinkumware\xlocale 657: Multiple declaration for 'codecvt<wchar_t,char,int>::out(int &,const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *,const wchar_t * &,char *,char *,char * &) const'
```

**Workarounds:**

```
enable rtti
```